# strange character in file name

Tags: filenames, rename

I usually name papers by copying/pasting the paper title name from a pdf file. For instance:
`peng2017-Induction of the pho regulon and polyphosphate synthesis?against spermine stress in Pseudomonas aeruginosa.pdf`.

The problem is that a strange character at the linebreak (after the word 'synthesis' in the example above) is copied and inserted in the filename and for that reason these files are not recognized by the (`rclone`) backup program.

How can we get rid of these linebreak character? 
The command `rename 's/[?<>\\:*|\"]/_/g' *` does not eliminate the '?' character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is actually a newline character and if, as seems to be the case from your question, you are using `perl-rename`, you can remove it with:

```
rename 's/\R/_/g' *pdf
```

The `\R` will match any [newline sequence](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#newlineseq):

> Outside a character class, by default, the escape sequence \R matches
>   any Unicode newline sequence. In 8-bit non-UTF-8 mode \R is equivalent
>   to the following:
>
> ```
>   (?>\r\n|\n|\x0b|\f|\r|\x85)
> ```